# Creating airflow in a mini greenhouse

Tags: homework-and-exercises, home-experiment, air

How do I create the best airflow for a mini victorian style greenhouse, that has a total volume of 80148.75 cm3? I leave the lid on top, which is a triangular prism in structure, open about 2.54 cm. I have then made small holes of 4 (each with diameter of just 4 mm and they are arranged like a cross) at the bottom of the back plexiglass sheet - a set on the right, a set on the centre and a set on the left side.

My question: How does the flow of air look like? I thought that the cooler air will go inside from the bottom holes and it will exit from the opening on the lid. But I'm not sure. I know when I turn on a blower behind the back plexiglass sheet, air does go in. From there I don't know if it circulates the inside and exits on top?? However, I'm most curious when I don't use a blower.

So, what is the airflow in this situation?

Appreciate your help. Your answer could help a number of orchid lovers, trying to grow them hydroponically indoors with limited space!

P.S.: Background for this question: Experiment on growing orchids in full water culture

Comment: Air density decreases as it heats. | Blow in some smoke.

Comment: Thanks Russell McMahon for your response. The thing is the humidity level and the temperature should be ideal for the orchids. At the same time there should be sufficient air movement to prevent diseases and mites. I think I'm lacking in the airflow factor. What do you mean by blowing in some smoke?

Comment: Smoke: Use to visibly observe airflow.

Comment: Anemometer MAY be able to measure convection airflows - although, may be too low.

Comment: Ahh yes. I did try the candle method but hard to see the movement. At the same time I don't want to create a hurricane! Perhaps a feather would do!

Comment: You can use a fan with a detector connected at an arduino for example and a switch at a relay?

Comment: Are you growing hydroponically or semi-hydroponically (ie with aliflor)?

Comment: Both but at the moment only hydroponically - just in water with nutrients. It is only a small collection not an orchard. I am aware of orchid forums but none so far really talks about the dynamics of airflow in a mini greenhouse.

Comment: If you are happy to use a fan but want low rate controlled flow it will be possible to make a controller that does what you want. It would also be possible, if these was demand to drive several entry points (or suck and use several exit points) and even to some extent to have different flow rates at different ports using mechanical constriction. Easiest would be to use a fan driven by a DC motor brushed motor as this can within quite wide limits be controlled easily without modifying the motor. Next easiest is a stepper motor where the motor is slightly more complex but not hard and then ....

Comment: ... harder but still not hard is to use a brushless DC motor. This is somewhat less convenient with most existing fans as you need to open them and perform minor surgery on the internal electronics to make them controllable. There are bare motoros avaiolable but these are usually more powerfuil than what you want - intended for use in eg RC models using and "ESC" (Engine speed controller) to control speed (no surprise). | None of this is very hard if you can get  good spec of what you want. ||You can get very small fans and motors mainly sold as toys for solar experimental use by ...

Comment: ... children. Made to run on single solar cell at ~= 0.5V. These could be solar powered or very low power battery powered or mains plug pack powered. | The very low voltage motors come packs like [this one](http://solarenergy.net/Resources/Images/News/SolarToys3.jpg) but this may not be very low voltage. Some digging will turn up something suitable. | If a number of people are interested in this then a BLDC motor version would be best with bare motor sourced to suit as it will be most controllable and can be very long life (no brushes). It's not technically hard - just a matter of doing it.

Comment: What country are you in? - affects supply of suitable components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your greenhouse is quite small, about 43cm on a side (if it's a cube), which means that small temperature differences won't create much convection. If you're worried about air flow, you'll probably have to use a fan to create it. Note, though, that you won't need a lot of air, and they make **very** quiet fans for computers, especially if you use a speed control to slow it down.

Comment: Thanks Daniel Grissom. I have actually taken out the fan from my old laptop, thinking I could use it for this purpose. The speed control is what's missing. Perhaps those small holes at the bottom with the top lid slightly open is enough then??

Comment: @RussellMcMahon's idea about "smoke" is a good one. You could use incense, or even use a glycerin-based fog generator (they make small, wand-shaped one for insulation and air leakage testing, as well as for toys).

Comment: Thanks @Daniel Grissom. I think I may have found my answer. Having two windows open on opposite sides of the building will exchange air well on a windy day, but not on a windless day. Similarly, if I simply provide holes at the bottom and an opening on top (opposite side), there will be no air movement in the greenhouse, because there is no wind inside my flat! Thus, I need to pull air from below, and push out air from above. An oscillating fan inside would circulate the air. That said, the size of my greenhouse is small, perhaps it's enough to just suck out the air from above!